# update sql table in php with condition after ajax x-editable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin

i need your help.

i made a code who create dynamically a new line in a table with ajax jquery.

```
var nouvelle_ligne = $('<tr><td class="thtime">'+hours+'h'+minutes+'</td><td>Modification de l\'équipe de Quart : <b class="textepersocdq">'+chefdequart+'</b> prend la fonction de Chef de Quart et <b class="textepersoadj">'+adjoint+'</b> prend celle d\'adjoint.</td><td class="button"><button class="editperso"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></button></td><td class="button"><button class="trashperso"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button></td></tr>').fadeIn('fast');
$('#tablemc').append(nouvelle_ligne);
```

In this new line, i have a button to edit the  with the x-editable library.

```
$(document).on("click", ".editperso", function(g){
g.stopPropagation();
  var $CellParent = $(this).closest('td').prev().children('b');
  editperso2($CellParent); });

function editperso2(bCellToEdit) {
bCellToEdit.editable({
  mode: 'inline',
  inputclass: 'input-medium texteperso',
  type: 'text',
  success: function() {
    var cmsperso = $('.textepersocms').next('span').children('div').children('form').children('div').children('div').children('div').children('input.texteperso').val();
    var chefdequart = $('.textepersocdq').next('span').children('div').children('form').children('div').children('div').children('div').children('input.texteperso').val();
    var adjoint = $('.textepersoadj').next('span').children('div').children('form').children('div').children('div').children('div').children('input.texteperso').val();
    var cmsperso2 = $(this).closest('td').children('.textepersocms').html();
    var chefdequart2 = $(this).closest('td').children('.textepersocdq').html();
    var adjoint2 = $(this).closest('td').children('.textepersoadj').html();

    console.log(cmsperso);
    console.log(chefdequart);
    console.log(adjoint);
    console.log(cmsperso2);
    console.log(chefdequart2);
    console.log(adjoint2);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "form/update/updateperso.php",
      async: false,
      data: { cmsperso: cmsperso, cmsperso2: cmsperso2, chefdequart: chefdequart, chefdequart2: chefdequart2, adjoint: adjoint, adjoint2: adjoint2 }
    });
  }
});}
```

this code transform the  to an input, the variable (adjoint, chefdequart and cmsperso are the new value and adjoint2, chefdequart2 and cmsperso2 are the value before change).

And finally i have php file who update a mysql table but it doesn't work.

```
elseif (empty($_POST['cmsperso']) && !empty($_POST['chefdequart']) && !empty($_POST['adjoint'])) {

    if (isset($_POST['chefdequart']) && isset($_POST['chefdequart2']) && isset($_POST['adjoint']) && isset($_POST['adjoint2'])) {

        $chefdequart = $_POST['chefdequart'];
        $chefdequart2 = $_POST['chefdequart2'];
        $adjoint = $_POST['adjoint'];
        $adjoint2 = $_POST['adjoint2'];

        $pos1 = strcasecmp($adjoint, $adjoint2);
        $pos2 = strcasecmp($chefdequart, $chefdequart2);

        if ($pos1===0 && $pos2!==0) { 

            $updateperso4 = "UPDATE `Operations` SET `chefdequart`=\"$chefdequart\" WHERE `cmsperso`='' AND `chefdequart`=\"$chefdequart2\" AND `adjoint`=\"$adjoint2\"";

            if($updateperso4) {
                echo json_encode(array("status"=>"ok"));
            }
            else {
                echo json_encode(array("status"=>"error", "error"=>"une erreur est survenue..."));
            }

            mysql_query($updateperso4, $cnx) or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_close();

        }

        elseif ($pos1!==0 && $pos2===0) {

            $updateperso5 = "UPDATE `Operations n°` SET `adjoint`=\"$adjoint\" WHERE `cmsperso`='' AND `chefdequart`=\"$chefdequart2\" AND `adjoint`=\"$adjoint2\"";

            if($updateperso5) {
                echo json_encode(array("status"=>"ok"));
            }
            else {
                echo json_encode(array("status"=>"error", "error"=>"une erreur est survenue..."));
            }

            mysql_query($updateperso5, $cnx) or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_close();

        }

        else { 
            echo "Ouppsss !"; 
        }

    }
}
```

when i put one of the Update to phpmyadmin, the update work and the value will change but in my code the value won't change.

when i try to chefdequart after insert chefdequart and adjoint, firebug return no error and this : 
[image: firebug]

and data change visually but no change in phpmyadmin.

I hope you understand me.
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subject solved with this

```
 if(cmsperso === undefined) { var cmsperso = $(this).closest('td').children('.textepersocms').html(); }
 if(chefdequart === undefined) { var chefdequart = $(this).closest('td').children('.textepersocdq').html(); }
 if(adjoint === undefined) { var adjoint = $(this).closest('td').children('.textepersoadj').html(); }
```

i test if my variable is undefined and i put the value i need, and ajax return the value

it's magic. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your UPDATE query is not executing as your `elseif` is -

```
elseif (empty($_POST['cmsperso']) && !empty($_POST['chefdequart']) && !empty($_POST['adjoint'])) {
```

and your `if` is -

```
if (isset($_POST['chefdequart']) && isset($_POST['chefdequart2']) && isset($_POST['adjoint']) && isset($_POST['adjoint2'])) {
```

Both of these require `$_POST['adjoint']`, but looking at your Firebug screen shot, you are only posting `chefdequart`, `chefdequart2`, and `adjoint2`

You need to look at your $.ajax `data:` as what you posted you should have 6 parameters (including `cmsperso` & `cmsperso2`), but Firebug is only showing 3.

Comment: yes this is exactly my problem the other posted data is "undefined" with cosole.log ! at the beginning, i have three input cmsperso, chefdequart and adjoint. when i insert only one and change, it work fine, my problem is when i insert two (example : chefdequart and adjoint) and change one of these, this not work.